# Remove "unless absolutely necessary" from suggested edits text

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits

When writing a suggested edit, the system says:

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial.
>   Avoid trivial, tiny one-letter edits **unless absolutely necessary**.

However, the system now rejects any edits with fewer than six characters, so I think the last part should be removed, since it's impossible to make a tiny suggested edit when necessary.

Comment: A different issue, but I believe the system should allow tiny edits. Iterative improvement is awesome. Plus just yesterday, I wanted to fix a post that had two spelling errors; but I couldn't. In that small post, there were enough errors to detract and distract, but not enough to get past the filter.

Comment: @Dogweather, there's *always* something else to fix, in my experience. I don't mean to pick on you, but [here's my edit on top of your recent suggested edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/20930498/revisions).

Comment: @Dogweather The system absolutely allows tiny edits, iterative improvement, etc. It doesn't allow tiny *suggested* edits. And for good reason; suggested edits use up the time of several users who could each otherwise be busy making edits directly, and they earn rep for the suggestor, so there's an entire reject reason around suggested edits being too minor. The minimum change limit is just an automated extension of that.

Answer (score 17):

Personally, I think "unless absolutely necessary" is not the problem.  I'd be more supportive of removing "tiny one-letter" instead.

> Your edit will be placed in a queue until it is peer reviewed.
>
> We welcome all constructive edits, but please make them substantial. Avoid trivial edits  unless absolutely necessary.

The reasoning is trivial edits are always discouraged unless absolutely necessary, regardless of the length, so it should be highlighted.  But as you mention, edits less than 6 characters are prohibited for suggested edits, so the "one letter" bit is unnecessary information for suggested editors.

Comment: That still doesn't read well to me. If an edit is absolutely necessary then by definition it isn't trivial (of little value or importance) anyway.

Comment: @MartinSmith you know what - 2 years later, I agree with you

Answer (score -2):

If the edit is **necessary** my way is to add an html comment like this:

`<!-- this is six characters-->`

Comment: What would be a case where this would be needed? Frankly there's always something else that can be edited and fixed (at least in my experience).

Comment: @hichris fixing minor typo in a title ( if we leave it like this it will not be recognized by search engines )(for future readers.)

Comment: Whenever there's a typo in the title, there's usually one in the body of the question.

Comment: @hichris assuming so, That makes it 2 characters not 6!

Comment: Could you direct me to one example of this (fixing a typo in the title)?

Comment: @hichris I can't find one right now but I will give you some example when I find it.

Comment: The answer is made community wiki to prevent downvotes... and it seems to be working...

Comment: @Lukasz The answer is made community wiki because it doesn't contain enough information, I will be updating soon. ( and btw why would you down vote such answer?)